# Better Approach for retrieving multiple RESTful calls

Tags: java, rest, android

I have an Android application that associates bluetooth beacons with data that is retrieved from a server via RESTful calls.

Once the app is launched, we have a page with a table that is being filled by data from the Bluetooth LE scanner.

My issue is this:

I have three data models:
 The `BluetoothAdvertisementModel`, which contains `AssociatedRoomDataModel` which contains a `AssociatedMeetingDataModel`.

My issue is that when I find a beacon, it immediately calls the server and ties that `BluetoothAdvertisementModel object` to an assigned  `AssociatedRoomDataModel object` (which is just a field for the `BluetoothAdvertisementModel` class).

Then once a `AssociatedRoomDataModel` is assigned, I retrieve via another `RESTful` call the `AssociatedMeetingDataModel` for that `AssociatedRoomDataModel`.

However, the issue with this approach is that it is rather slow even with using `AsyncTask` calls.

Any idea on a better approach?

Comment: I'm not really sure what does this mean. If you could provide a little context on what is Dataset, Item, and what the App do (or an analogy) that'd help

Comment: Certainly, let me write that up.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed better. I could understand your system uses an Android rest-client app, and a server, but you might wanna write that up so that other people understand it faster than I did :P

Comment: Also, is the app's objective to send those ads to the scanned bluetooth beacons?  or is it backwards?

Comment: It's receiving the ads and constructing the data model FROM a bluetooth device.

Comment: App listens -> finds bluetooth device -> creates data object from bluetooth's advertisement packets -> populates list